# How to convert Json to html form and Post back?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to convert a `json` array (that is fetched from backend) to a dynamic html form:

```
{
    "journeys": [
        {
            "origin": "New York"
            "destination": "San Francisco"
            "distance": 4670
        },
        {
            //repeat the above N times
        }
    ]
}
```

While it would be ease to generate 3 inputs for each array element, how can I actually `POST` them back to backend after editing?

I mean, normally each `<input>` element has a `name` attribute that is used as query parameter in get/post requests.

But how could I actually post the modified `json` equivalent here?

```
<form>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="origin1" class="form-label">Origin</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="origin1">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="destination1" class="form-label">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="destination1">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3 form-check">
    <label for="distance1" class="form-label">Distance</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="distance1">
  </div>
  
  <!-- repeat the above N times, with id="originN" / "destinationN" / "distanceN" -->
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: are you wanting the [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) maybe? with XMLHttpRequest or fetch maybe?

Comment: what do you mean by `Post back`?

Comment: I mean posting back the edited values to the backend, again as json.

Comment: Do you mean after you generating the HTML regards to the json you received from backend, you send the information in the same structure as the received json from the HTML to the backend again when you click the submit button?

Comment: Yes exactly that's my plan. I'm actually looking for a nice way to edit a json array. Of course editing makes only sense if the changes can be send back to the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new FormData()` and loop `formData.entries()` to construct the data you need.

```js
const data = {
  journeys: [
    {
      origin: "New York",
      destination: "San Francisco",
      distance: 4670,
    },
    {
      origin: "Australia",
      destination: "Sydney",
      distance: 2300,
    },
  ],
};
//create HTML
for (const { origin, destination, distance } of data.journeys) {
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  form.innerHTML = `
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label class="form-label">Origin</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='origin' value='${origin}'/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label  class="form-label">Destination</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='destination' value='${destination}'/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
      <label class="form-label">Distance</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='distance' value='${distance}'/>
    </div>
  `;
  document.querySelector("section").appendChild(form);
}

//add addEventListener to send data to backend
document.querySelector("#btn1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll("form");
  const updatedData = { journeys: [] };
  forms.forEach(form => {
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const journey = {};
    for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      if (key === "distance") {
        journey[key] = Number(value);
      } else {
        journey[key] = value;
      }
    }
    updatedData.journeys.push(journey);
  });
  console.log(updatedData);
});
```

```html
<section></section>
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I have updated some of the code from the answer of @ikhvjs to increase the field id with the N element when it is rendering. Thanks for the answer @ikhvjs**

And Yes I kept the first element as it is so if you don't want you can remove that HTML code.

```js
const data = {
  journeys: [
    {
      origin: "New York",
      destination: "San Francisco",
      distance: 4670,
    },
    {
      origin: "Australia",
      destination: "Sydney",
      distance: 2300,
    },
    {
      origin: "Australia 1",
      destination: "Sydney 1",
      distance: 2301,
    },
    {
      origin: "Australia 2",
      destination: "Sydney 2",
      distance: 2302,
    },
  ],
};
var increment = 2;
for (const { origin, destination, distance } of data.journeys) {
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  form.innerHTML = `<hr/>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="origin'${increment}'" class="form-label">Origin</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='origin' id="origin'${increment}'" value='${origin}'/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="destination'${increment}'" class="form-label">Destination</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='destination' id="destination'${increment}'" value='${destination}'/>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
      <label for="distance'${increment}'" class="form-label">Distance</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='distance' id="distance'${increment}'" value='${distance}'/>
    </div>
  `;
  document.querySelector("jsonresponse").appendChild(form);
  increment++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="my_test_form">
  
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="origin1" class="form-label">Origin</label>
    <input type="text" name="origin[]" class="form-control" id="origin1">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="destination1" class="form-label">Destination</label>
    <input type="text" name="destination[]" class="form-control" id="destination1">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3 form-check">
    <label for="distance1" class="form-label">Distance</label>
    <input type="text" name="distance[]" class="form-control" id="distance1">
  </div>
  <jsonresponse></jsonresponse>
  <!-- repeat the above N times, with id="originN" / "destinationN" / "distanceN" -->
  
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```